# if beLongsTo is empty for particular item return another belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to return the customer adress if there is no deliveretadress on the order.

This what I have been trying:

```
public function deliveryAddress()
{
    if ( $this->delivery_address )
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("DeliveryAddress",'delivery_address');
    }
    return $this->belongsTo("Customer", 'customer_id');
}
```

This does not work if I want to use Order::with('deliveryAddress')->get(), only If I have a model and not a collection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a relation you still don't have a row available, relations are queries in the process of built, this way, you still don`t have`delivery_address` available here:

```
if ( $this->delivery_address )
```

Because at this point your model is still not up. It (or they) will be up after a `get()` or a `first()` and then you'll have access to them. So you can

```
public function deliveryAddress()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("DeliveryAddress",'delivery_address');
}

public function customerAddress()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("Customer", 'customer_id');
}

class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function getAddress()
    {
        if ($this->delivery_address)
        {
            return $this->deliveryAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->customerAddress;
        }
    }

}

$order = Order::with('deliveryAddress', 'customerAddress')->first();

echo $order->getAddress()->street_name;
```

This is untested code, so it might not work at first, but this is the idea of what you can do.

Comment: Thx man. I did want to be able to do a conditional eagerload. But I see that is probably not easily done. But eagerloading both adresses in and then using the helper function is a great idea!